# Unwanted Margin in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainRlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/moflow_main_screen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtMoflow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/initCapsText"
    android:text="MoFlow"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="#FA3248"
    android:typeface="serif" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/initCapsText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/startBtn"
    android:text="TESTING"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/startBtn" 
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/manageBtn"
        android:text="Start Testing" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/manageBtn" 
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Management" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/optionsBtn" 
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/manageBtn"
        android:text="Options" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/aboutBtn" 
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/optionsBtn"
        android:text="About" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/quitBtn" 
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/aboutBtn"
        android:text="Quit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the image view picture to go all the way down to the screen, but there is a margin at the bottom and I don't know where it's coming from. I thought it might be the image dimensions, but even setting to 1000x1000 pixels doesn't do anything to get rid of the margins, neither does setting alignParentBottom.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: marginProblem]

Comment: Can't reproduce that. Any chance you can post a screenshot? (You can take device screenshots via the `ddms` tool from the `ANDROID_SDK/tools` folder. Just select the device and go to `Device -> Screen capture`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the image you are using match the dimensions of the screen?

If not:

Try setting `android:scaleType="fitXY"` on the `ImageView`
- This will scale the image to fit the screen but will not retain the images original aspect ratio.

If you want to maintain the aspect ratio `android:scaleType="center"` will center the image with no scaling and maintains aspect ratio.  However it will crop the image if it is larger than the screen, or it will not fill the screen if it is too small.

For other scale  types, check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Hope this helps

Comment: The question remains though...if the image I used was extremely large, large enough for a small screen, why is there a margin at the bottom as shown in the screen shot?

Comment: I believe, by default, the image will be scaled to fit the screen while maintaining the aspect ratio.  Which will cause the margin if the aspect ratio of the image does not match the aspect ratio of the screen.